# IR2133 Bridge driver not working as expected

Tags: power-electronics, mosfet-driver, low-side, high-side

I want to use the IR2133 to drive a mosfet rectifier. I have setup as in the circuit below

[image]

The probelm is (take first high side fet as example) that the signal that appears on HO1 is exactly the same as whats on VS1. The gate voltage VGS should should be VS1 + turn on voltage(30V) when the PWM signal on HIN1 is activated. The PWM has no effect on the signal whatsoever whether disconnected or not.

Do perhaps some of the other pins need to be set to enable this functionality and should this behaviour be expected in this configuration?

Edit 1:

Below is a plot of the PWM signal and the (low voltage) AC signal taken from HO1 and is the same as the input signal.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: They are not MOSFETs; they are IGBTs. If you applied 30 volts Vgs most mosfets would be damaged. Are you really feeding the bridge supply AC?

Comment: How are you bootstrapping it? Show oscillograms!

Comment: @Andy aka Schematic is taken from the data sheet but same setup for mosfets. Yes I am feeding the bridge supply AC as I want to rectify the signal.

Comment: @winny I believe the dio.de and capacitor is used for bootstrapping but I'm not sure if it works right

Comment: Me neither, that's why I'm asking you to take oscillograms. I bet you two bucks your duty cycle is too high or switch frequency too low.

Comment: @winny I have added a pic which shows the pwm and signal out on HO1

Comment: Right, so 50 Hz. What's your bootstrap capacitor value? Is it big as your hand?

Comment: More like as small as my nail. But it should only hold a small charge, say 20V and hold onto it for some time. Why so large?

Comment: So how did you dimension it? Show values in your schematic. Simulate it.

Comment: Still getting my head around how the IC works. Very little documentation detailing it. Any references would be great.

Answer (score 1):

With an AC supply connected directly to your Vs pins how do you avoid this: -

[image]

- VB1,2,3 cannot go more than 0.3 volts negative relative to GND
- VS1,2,3 cannot go more than 25 volts below VB1,2,3

Personally I think you need to swap load and bridge power connections.

Comment: As stated in the datasheet " All voltage
parameters are absolute voltages referenced to COM". So if your in the negative half cycle (say -600)  so as VS and VB alternate they should be ok???

Comment: @MXG123 you can't take VS1,2, or 3 below 0.3 volts negative. It doesn't mean ABS(x) if that's what you meant?

Comment: Maybe this device is not suitable for my needs. Is it possible to raise the source voltage Vthreshold above to turn on. I can connect the source to gate with a resistor so they are equal and put a dc source in series. However putting a dc source in series is tricky to do.

Comment: Is the question finished now or do you have further comments that need clarifying?